# Java Selenium chromedriver error

Tags: 20.04, java, selenium

Chromedriver is located at the same place as this file.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public WebDriver getDriver(final String browser) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = null;
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
```

**error: package import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver does not exist**

**error: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
does not exist**

I have refered to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806955/error-package-org-openqa-selenium-doesnt-exist%5B1%5D) but failed to resolve it

Here is `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.selenium.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumMavenDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>               
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                  </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I need some more info here. Are you using a build automation tool like Maven? What do you use to build the Java application (command line, IDE, or something else?)?

Comment: Just to be clear: the described error has nothing to do with the location of the chrome driver file. It means that the JVM cannot find the Selenium Java library.

Comment: @SimonBaars I am using Maven for automation

Comment: VS code with java plugin @SimonBaars

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. Have you installed both the vs code Java and Maven plugins? Are you sure you run the program using Maven? Can you share your `pom.xml`?
PS: Here is a guide showing how to properly use Maven with VS code: https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/vs-code-for-java-and-maven-projects

Comment: I have edited the post and added pom.xml @SimonBaars

Comment: I have already installed microsoft extension for java for vscode @SimonBaars

Comment: The Maven file seems correct, but for some reason your IDE does not seem to be using Maven to build the project. Can you make sure you are running the project through the Maven builder and not just Java. Do you have the Maven extension?

Comment: Yes. I have maven extension.@SimonBaars

Comment: I'd need to see your setup... Is the source file you shared the entire content of the source file? Or are you missing the package declaration? In which package is your source file located?